# Handlebars doesn't seem to call my controller function

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a property on my controller, `isLogin`, bound to a handlebars conditional, `{{#unless isLogin}}`. But it doesn't seem to activate the function when the template is rendered. I inserted a `console.log` statement and that doesn't show up in the console either.

I have an application template like this:

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="screen-line black"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1-6">
      {{#unless isLogin}}
        <div class="nav pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
          <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><div class="menu-item-icon fa fa-trello"></div>{{link-to "Classrooms" "classrooms" class="menu-item pure-menu-link"}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      {{/unless}}
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-5-6" >
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="screen-line black"></div>
</div>
```

And a controller like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isLogin : function(){
    console.log("isLogin called");
    return true;
  }

});
```

Can you see what is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should make `isLogin` into a property, like the following:

```
// controllers/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  isLogin: function(){
    console.log("isLogin called");
    return true;
  }.property()

});
```

(see [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bumocuzoco/1/edit?html,js,output))

Answer (score 0):

I think your way of implementation is wrong.

You should do it in below way - isLogin should be a variable in your controller and you can change the value of this variable in any controller functions like init(). As below -

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
isLogin: false,  
init:function()
    {
        this._super(); 
        this.set('isLogin',true);

    }
});
```

then you can use this variable in your Unless inside your template.
[Just a Note- I am calling this.super() in init method only because i don't want to override any of the original functionality of controller's init.]